# Why are my attachments not sending in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, email-attachments

I am still having problems trying to send image attachments from an email form. What I want to happen is the user submits some information, then they upload an image via the client, and then when they hit submit, that image is sent to me as an e-mail. I have not been able to get this to work and I don't know why. I have been looking everywhere for days now, watching tutorials, reading documentation, playing around, reading answers and trying to figure this out but obviously I am not understanding how to implement the code to get the attachment to appear with an email and have an image within it when I open it in the email. Can some one help me? Here is my code and thank you:

```
const express = require("express");
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const app = express();
const creds = require("./config");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(fileUpload());
app.use(cors());

app.post("/api/form", (req, res) => {
  nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
    const htmlEmail = `
      <h3>Contact Details</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>
          Name: ${req.body.name}
        </li>
        <li>
          Email: ${req.body.email}
        </li>     
      </ul>
       <h3>Message</h3>
      <p>${req.body.message}</p>
    `;

    let transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "some.service.email",
      port: ***,
      auth: {
        user: creds.USER,
        pass: creds.PASS,
      },
    });

    let mailOptions = {
      from: "test@test.com",
      to: "receiveTest@test.com",
      replyTo: "test@test.com",
      subject: "Test Message",
      text: req.body.message,
      html: htmlEmail,
      attachments: [ //The problem area. This won't appear in a sent email.
        {
          filename: "AdImage.jpg",
          content: req.body.file,
          contentType: "image/jpg",
        },
      ],
    };

    transport.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
      if (err) {
        res.json({
          status: "fail",
        });
      } else {
        res.json({
          status: "success",
        });
      }
    });
  });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

EDIT:
So I changed the code a bit to look like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const app = express();
const creds = require("./config");
const cors = require("cors");
const fs = require("fs");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(fileUpload());
app.use(cors());

app.post("/api/form", (req, res) => {
  nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
    console.log(req.files.file);
    const htmlEmail = `
      <h3>Contact Details</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>
          Name: ${req.body.name}
        </li>
        <li>
          Email: ${req.body.email}
        </li>     
      </ul>
       <h3>Message</h3>
      <p>${req.body.message}</p>
    `;

    let transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "some.service.email",
      port: ***,
      auth: {
        user: creds.USER,
        pass: creds.PASS,
      },
    });

    let mailOptions = {
      from: "test@test.com",
      to: "receiveTest@test.com",
      replyTo: "test@test.com",
      subject: "Test Message",
      text: req.body.message,
      html: htmlEmail,
      attachments: [
        {
          filename: req.files.file.name,
          content: new Buffer.from(req.files.file.name, "utf-8"),
        },
      ],
    };

    transport.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
      if (err) {
        res.json({
          status: "fail",
        });
      } else {
        res.json({
          status: "success",
        });
      }
    });
  });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

So now my e-mail is getting attachments but the attachment is empty and returns a server error if I attempt to download it. The log shows the file. It shows this:

```
name: 'myFile.jpg',
[0]   data: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 02 01 01 01 01 01 02 01 01 01 02 02 02 02 02 04 03 02 02 02 02 05 04 04 03 ... 992910 more bytes>,
[0]   size: 992960,
[0]   encoding: '7bit',
[0]   tempFilePath: '',
[0]   truncated: false,
[0]   mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
[0]   md5: 'f383f6170d8a66f90be655690ee3f51e',
[0]   mv: [Function: mv]
```

I am not understanding why I still cant see the actual image in the attachment. What else am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: You are using content. According to doc `content` required buffer file. Is your `req.body.file` is buffer type?

Comment: I don't know. Its an image file. How do I know what content type an image file is, specifically a jpeg? The nodemailer documentation isn't really clear on this.

Comment: @ShubhamVerma Ok so I did a `console.log` on the server side and the file is being read by the server. I am assuming its a buffer but I don't know. The log shows this:

`name: 'myfile.jpg',
[0]   data: <Buffer ff d8 ff (a bunch of numbers) ...992910 more bytes>,
[0]   size: 992960,
[0]   encoding: '7bit',
[0]   tempFilePath: '',
[0]   truncated: false,
[0]   mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
[0]   md5: 'f383f6170d8a66f90be655690ee3f51e',
[0]   mv: [Function: mv]`
So everything looks correct but I am not for sure how to set up a buffer instance. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For post requests to express, you have to use a body parser, unlike get requests. Here is one from npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser.

Scroll down the npm page to find some examples on how to use it.

Comment: I tried using several body parsers like busboy and body-parser and I couldn't get them to work. Can you provide an example of a body parser that works with sending an actual image? None of the examples I could find had working examples for images like jpgs, just text files.

Comment: I re-added in body-parser but I am still having the same problem, attachments are not showing up in my email. I don't understand what I am missing :(